TypeError: Response.json is not a function for jest testing with NestJs routes and Prisma
I am using NextJs routes, Prisma and Postgres. My user route works, but the test does not. I get the error message:
TypeError: Response.json is not a function
For the line in route.ts
return NextResponse.json({data: users}, {status: 200});
But it works in test it manually to a local host web page.
/src/app/api/users/route.ts
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";

// routes /api/users

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      last_name: 'asc',
    }
  })
  return NextResponse.json({data: users}, {status: 200});
}

/test/app/api/users/route.test.tsx
import { GET } from '@/app/api/users/route';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
// import { prisma } from '@/lib/prisma';
import { prisma } from '../../../../src/lib/prisma';

// Mock the Prisma module
// jest.mock('@/lib/prisma', () => ({
jest.mock('../../../../src/lib/prisma', () => ({  
  prisma: {
    user: {
      findMany: jest.fn(),
    },
  },
}));

describe('GET /api/users', () => {
  it('should return an array of users sorted by last name', async () => {
    const mockedRequest = {} as NextRequest;
    const mockedUsers = [
      { id: 1, last_name: 'User A' },
      { id: 2, last_name: 'User B' },
    ];

    // Mock the behavior of prisma.user.findMany
    (prisma.user.findMany as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(mockedUsers);

    // Call the GET function with the mocked request
    const response = await GET(mockedRequest);

    // Assert that prisma.user.findMany has been called with the correct parameters
    expect(prisma.user.findMany).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      orderBy: {
        last_name: 'asc',
      },
    });

    // Assert the response
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body).toEqual({ data: mockedUsers });
  });
});

I was expecting the test to pass. I tried to format the output as
return NextResponse.json({data: bowls}, {status: 200}) as unknown as any;
but I still get the same error

Share a Sandbox/repo that reproduce the issue?
